# Сумма элементов массива после первого отрицательного числа

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо найти сумму элементов массива после нахождения первого отрицательного элемента и вывести все элементы после первого отрицательного элемента. Например есть массив `{0,2,-5,7,4,9,3,-2,5,4,5}` необходимо найти первое отрицательное число, здесь `-5`, затем вывести сумму оставшихся элементов `7,4,9,3,-2,5,4,5}`.
У меня не совсем вышло:

```
    int[]arr = {0,2,-5,7,4,9,3,-2,5,4,5};

    int firstNegative = 0;
    int countIndex = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        countIndex++;
        if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            firstNegative = arr[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < (arr.length - countIndex); j++)
            {
                sum+=arr[j];
            }
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("My first: " + firstNegative);
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: "У меня не совсем вышло" - может скажете, что вышло?

Comment: я считаю сумму но с нулевого индекса `sum+=arr[j]` а как считать с индекса где находится первое отрицательное число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша идея со вторым циклом, я бы сказал, не очень хорошая. Если вы прочитаете задачу внимательно, то стане понятно, что вам нужно просто пропускать элементы до того, как найдете первое отрицательное число.

```
    int[] arr = {0, 2, -5, 7, 4, 9, 3, -2, 5, 4, 5};
    boolean firstNegativeFound = false;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!firstNegativeFound && arr[i] < 0) {
            firstNegativeFound = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (firstNegativeFound) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); //35
```

Comment: ТС вроде бы хочет складывать отрицательные числа, кроме первого.

Comment: @igor В задании сказано 'затем вывести сумму оставшихся элементов 7,4,9,3,-2,5,4,5}' то есть все после первого отрицательного.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно!

Comment: Вообще конечно задачка явно учебная и автору нужно было подумать самому немного перед тем как спрашивать.

Comment: @MikhailChibel Ваш код не добавляет отрицательные числа в сумму.

Comment: @Igor спасибо поправил.